# What is a rule and how to inherit it and edit it in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo-10, odoo

So I created this user named `Eric` and I want him to manage all the features in gamification module. When I go to gamification security I found these rules:

```xml
<record id="goal_user_visibility" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">User can only see his/her goals or goal from the same challenge in board visibility</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_gamification_goal"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[
        '|',
            ('user_id','=',user.id),
            '&amp;',
                ('challenge_id.user_ids','in',user.id),
                ('challenge_id.visibility_mode','=','ranking')]</field>
</record>

<record id="goal_gamification_manager_visibility" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Manager can see any goal</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_gamification_goal"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_erp_manager'))]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[(1, '=', 1)]</field>
</record>
```

But I can't find them in the user interface so I can put Eric in one of them. Isn't a rule the same as a group? If not how can I deal with this? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, this is a really good question, but not really a programming one, more a configuration one. Try to ask this question in the [official Odoo forums](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about configuring a software and not about programming for or with this software.

Comment: read official documentation...